# Android - persisting data in Service

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I'm using Firebase for Push Notifications. The problem is that notifications are not saved if my application is closed and only NotificationService is running in background.

Saving is working in case my application is running.

How I should persist data inside a service ?

```
NotificationReceiver extends FirebaseMessaginService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    saveNotification(buildNotificationObjet(remoteMessage));

    if(getPreference("displayNotifications") != 0) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
}


private void saveNotification(Notification notification) {
        new PersistTask(getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME,  Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)).execute(notification);
    }
```

Saving is done in PersistTask

```
private static class PersistTask extends AsyncTask<Notification, Void, List<Notification>> {

    SharedPreferences preferences;

    public PersistTask(SharedPreferences preferences) {
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Notification> doInBackground(Notification... paramNotification) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Notification>>(){}.getType();


        List<Notification> notifications = gson.fromJson(preferences.getString(PREFERENCE_LIST_NAME, ""), type);
        if(notifications == null) {
            notifications = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        notifications.addAll(Arrays.asList(paramNotification));

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(PREFERENCE_LIST_NAME, gson.toJson(notifications));
        editor.apply();

        return notifications;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna make an assumption here (hence not an actual answer). I believe that after onMessageReceived() returns, firebase service doesn't have any more work to do and finishes itself. Which makes Android kill the VM before your AsyncTask can be executed. My suggestion for you is to create an `IntentService` to execute this action safely on a Background thread. Notification is Parcelable, so you can pass on an Intent and you can call `getSharedPreferences` from it.

Comment: No, I have tried to run without async task. I think is something related to context in witch Services are started.

Comment: Hence, using an IntentService, the context it will be your own application context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that when using FireBase, there are 2 type of push notifications.

1. Payload with "notification" will not be handled by registered service for receiving push notifications.
2. Payload with "data" content, will be handled by registered service.

From Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive):

onMessageReceived is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

- **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
- **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Answer (score 0):

`onMessageReceived` is going to be invoked on a background thread, so you should not use an `AsyncTask` here. Just do your stuff directly in this method synchronously.

Comment: This will not resolve my problem. I have tried in both ways,

Comment: What about using `editor.commit()` instead of `editor.apply()`?